# Using Crypt Gem (Ruby On Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am attempting to use the crypt gem. While I am able to get it installed via bundler, when I do:

```
require 'crypt/rijndael'
```

I got an error:
no such file to load -- crypt/rijndael

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Crypt? Which version of Ruby?  Where are you trying to require it from?  I tried Crypt 1.1.4 on Ruby 1.8.7 and it worked for me in the rails console:

```
ruby-1.8.7-p334 :001 > require 'crypt/rijndael'
=> ["Crypt"] 
ruby-1.8.7-p334 :002 >
```

If you're using 1.9, try crypt 1.2.1 instead:

https://github.com/titanous/crypt

Haven't tested it myself, but give it a shot if you're on 1.9

Comment: server needed a restart! Doh!